# Checking if my ISP supports IP multicast

Tags: ip, isp, multicast

I want to cast a live stream and can't tell if my ISP will support multicast or not.

How do I check whether my ISP supports IP multicast?

Comment: Call them. They have a phone number or email support don't they?

Comment: Is there any application/tool to check this capability?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been categorised as off-topic. Running a tool is a matter of seconds, and can be integrated in a client software. Calling the ISP is another matter...

Answer (score 0):

1. Call your ISP.
2. Check the Terms of Use you agreed to when you started the service.
3. Check the website for a support FAQ that might include this information.
4. Email your ISP's support department.